# Is there an algorithm like shamir secret sharing that allows arbitrary length inputs?

Tags: secret-sharing

As far as I understand it, when using Shamir's secret sharing algorithm, you have to specify a finite field for your operations that is big enough to hold your data.

I tried to look for secret sharing algorithms, but I only get results for Shamir's secret sharing algorithm ..

Are there other algorithms or do I just store the field size together with the secrets?

Comment: Do you know how to encrypt arbitrary-length data with a block cipher? Do you see a parallel?

Comment: Hm ... I am not sure how I would apply what I know from encryption since an IV is used most of the time, but assuming I use GF(2^256), do I just make secret chunks of <= 256 bit length (do I need padding here? I don't think so, right?) and calculate the shares for each chunk and then distribute them accordingly? This would indeed make perfect sense to me, am I missing anythig? What about the IV? Is it necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joseph's comment alludes to, the usual solution for arbitrary-length secrets is symmetric encryption, with the encryption key itself (which has a known, fixed length) distributed using the secret-sharing scheme. In fact, this is literally the primary use case for SSS, per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing):

> Shamir's Secret Sharing (SSS) is used to secure a secret in a distributed way, most often to secure other encryption keys.

Generate a secure random key, probably 128 or 256 bits, for each secret you want to share. Encrypt the secret with a good cipher, using a well-designed library such as [libsodium](https://doc.libsodium.org/); this should take care of ensuring there's an appropriate IV/NOnce and authentication tag. Share the encryption key using SSS.

The location of the encrypted secret can be public, or the entire encrypted secret can be copied in full along with each share. The public metadata about the encryption (the cipher and mode used, the IV or nonce, the authentication tag or signature) is distributed along with the encrypted secret; they are not secret and the only requirement is that they they be available when the secret is to be decrypted.

Comment: Okay, so it is sufficient to share the keys. What about different key sizes though, how do I know how big the key that was shared was originally? Can I depend on the length of the shares? Or can I, at least, implement it in a way to depend only on the length of the shares? I would choose a field according to the key size d and for any share I would pad it with 0 on the left so that it has exactly d bit length. I could then convert it to base64 for storage but yeah, would this be feasible?

Comment: Well, in the end it all depends on how much information is stored in the algorithm used for decryption and how much is stored with the shares, right? When I use the same implementation for decryption I can throw away things like the key size,  the algorithm used and where the key is stored in the secrets etc., otherwise I need to add this information to the shares in a way that they are easily readable ...

Comment: Things like choice of cipher and key size are not secret! You store them in plain text along with the encrypted secret. You pick a field according to the key size, which again, every stakeholder (and possibly anybody else who is mildly curious) knows. The shares contain *nothing* except the (parts of the) key. Everything else, including the key size, is public. This may sound dangerous, but an essential element of modern cipher design is that the attacker is already assumed to know everything except the key.